# Showing results in another page if there is more than two records

Tags: java, html, jsp

I have a small program which reads the file path from Server Directory and display it as a link to the report folder something like report1.html.

```
      Folder Structure ROOT>REPORTS>COMPANY_NAME>January>report1.html
```

In My html Page it looks like this:

```
     Company Name

         -January( href to the report1.html)
```

HTML which renders result

```
   #foreach( $reportGroup in ${orgReport.reportGroupList})
      <br><tr>${reportGroup.ReportGroupName}</tr><br>
        #foreach( $report in ${reportGroup.reportList})
            <tr><a href="${report.ReportPath}">${report.reportId}</a></tr><br>
         #end
     #end 

 </table>
```

How to display in another page if there is more than one href link.

Comment: How r u setting `href` of `a` tag to the specific *file path* ? R u using any JSTL expression ?

Comment: Yes,I just added HTML above.

Comment: U mean, u want `${report.ReportPath}` path available from this expression on some other page or something else ? How is the structure of your pages & links ?

Comment: Correct, for example if there are multiple href it will make my webpage look messy. To resolve this I need to display list of href in separate page if it's more than two href. If user click on January ,it will take user to separate page  with list of href.

Comment: If u have added `reportList` in session then u can access it anywhere, right. Instead of creating `links` while iterating `reportGroupList` list u can create `div`, give `id` to each `div` and add click event on it which will call html file just like `Report1.html,Report2.html,etc`. Then on respective pages populate your data available in `reportList` & create `links` there. I didn't tested this but, u can try something like this.

Comment: I have tried to do things like in above comment. See my answer. Try it. Hope it will solve your problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this

```
<%@ taglib prefix="fn" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/functions" %>

<c:forEach var="reportGroupList" items="${orgReport.reportGroupList}" varStatus="loop">
    <div onclick="window.open('Report${loop.index}.html', '_blank',
         top=500, left=500, width=400, height=400);">
             ${reportGroupList.ReportGroupName} Report${loop.index}
    </div>
</c:forEach>
```

In respective *Report.html* you can populate list of links to report path just like below

```
<c:forEach var="report" items="${sessionScope.reportList}">
    <tr><a href="${report.ReportPath}">${report.reportId}</a></tr>
</c:forEach>
```

Comment: Quite helpful but page did not render this is the output ${reportGroup.ReportGroupName} Report${loop.index} but not the values

Comment: @Lokesh *this is the output ${reportGroup.ReportGroupName} Report${loop.index} but not the values* means ? I didn't get exactly ? At what stage u r now ? Did u get list of pages in first loop ? **I think there is a mistake in name of var in first loop. It is `reportGroupList` & I wrote `${reportGroup.ReportGroupName}`. It should be `${reportGroupList.ReportGroupName}`**. I have updated my answer with this change. Let's try this change.